# Riddle within a riddle

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

Welcome to this puzzle, friends.
   This riddle inside it contains
      The keys to find its own success.
         I throughout these lines have spread
            The letters needed to solve it all.
               And so do you make search in vain,
                  For all of the clues you'll verily need.
                     Ne'er doubt, nestling snugly herein:
                     Solution! It sends you happily off
                  Into an everlasting puzzlers' bliss
               That descends upon successful solvers.
            Count and you see, the answer
         Really to itself points clearly.
      Exactly in the middle, too,
   Twice it is seen, even, just to confirm,
Once clear and once reversed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> Nest

The question is

> Where do birds live

Found by

> Removing spaces and punctuation, taking 1st letter of 1st line, 2nd letter of 2nd line, etc., which is hinted at in the first part of the riddle.

Also

> the last 4 lines point to nest and tsen found in the middle of the riddle

here is a visual

> [image]

Comment: Great answer, how creative. :)

Comment: Absolutely right. I'm glad all the hints fell together - it felt like the kind of puzzle that might lead to people barking up wrong trees. And nice visual at the end!

Comment: Oh no, hope that they don't bark up this tree :(